# misbehave javascript when the associate class has multiple instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Js snippet below work for single html table (class = mtable), basically it will freeze the first column when i scroll left on the table.  it misbehave when i have multiple "mtable" class html table where scroll at one table will cause all the table scroll at the same time.  How should i fix this so that each table will work independently?

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.mtable tbody', function(){
    // alert('scrolling');
    $('.mtable tbody').on('scroll', function() {
      $('.mtable thead').css("left", -$(".mtable tbody").scrollLeft());
      $('.mtable thead tr th:first-child').css("left", $(".mtable tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
      $('.mtable tbody tr td:first-child').css("left", $(".mtable tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a reference to the current `.mtable` element and then call the DOM traversal functions based on that table only, something like this:

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.mtable tbody', function() {
  var $tbody = $(this);
  var $table = $tbody.closest('.mtable');
  var $thead = $table.find('thead');

  var $tbody = $table.find('tbody').off('scroll').on('scroll', function() {
    $thead.css("left", -$tbody.scrollLeft());
    $thead.find('tr th:first-child').css("left", $tbody.scrollLeft() - 2);
    $tbody.find('tr td:first-child').css("left", $tbody.scrollLeft() - 2);
  });
});
```

Comment: You got it right before me. One thing to add: Every time a mouseover happens, a new scroll event is added to the target `.mtable tbody`. Personally, I would move the reference points inside the scroll event callback, and eliminate the outer mouseover altogether.

Comment: amazing.  i think i need to spend some time to learn javscript from inside out :)

Comment: @maiorano84 makes a good point about the repeated handlers. I added an `off()` call to negate it, but it's still not ideal. I'd suggest re-thinking how you are dealing with this logic, but I'm glad you got it working at least